# Installed WinForm App throws error "a network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server"

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, exe, sql-server-2014

I have created a setup of my vb.net win application and installed it successfully on another pc. The database file is also restored in other pc SQL server but the problem is that when i run my app it doesn't connect to the SQL server and throws the error

> a network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server

I tried alot but its still not getting fixed. All SQL Server instances are running and i have checked and restarted many time but i wonder why this problem is occuring because in my main pc this app is running perfectly fine.
Any solutions for this?
Regards

Update//
The Port is enabled and its already 1433. This is the app.config code:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbx" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DemoDb;User Id=sa;password=123456#"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="db.My.MySettings.MasterDemoConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=Demo;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In the sql configuration manager check if the protocols have TCP/IP enabled. Also check if the sqlserver browser service is running on the machine where sql server is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable TCP/IP in the configuration manager .Also, you need to configure a TCP port (1433) on which the SQL Server service is listening. If you accessing database via network, then you need to open specified port in the firewall. Can you provide us your connection string?

Try Data Source = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have checked your account name and password for the SQL server.

Is your SQL Server running? If not type `services.msc` in Run (ctrl + r). And look for the `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`, right-click it and then click start.

Comment: yes the sql is running but when i execute the app it opens smoothly. the only problem is that it doesn't connect to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

***If you will checkout few things then I think that your problem will be solve.***

***Remove your Double Connection string from app.config ***

> step 1 : Check you Connection string (Data Source is very important because u have shifted your database to another pc thats why)

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=dbFactory;User ID=sa; password=user@123"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

> step 2 : clean your project solution

Right Click on solution and click on clean then your old bin file remove and build again your project then your new bin file create in your for your setup.

> step 3 : Is your SQL Server running?

If you want to check then press **window + r** and type **services.msc** in Run. And find your **SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)** and view status of this service and if status will come stop/pause then press right-click on this service and choose start then status will change in start.

> step 4 : TCP/IP

If you are using LAN for accessing database then check you have enable TCP/IP in the configuration manager

Answer (score 0):

Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename.

Please try below.. hope this will help you.

`<add name="dbx" connectionString="Data Source=machinename\instancename;Initial Catalog=DemoDb;User Id=sa;password=123456#"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Answer (score 0):

In the sql configuration manager check if the protocols have TCP/IP enabled. Also check if the sqlserver browser service is running on the machine where sql server is installed.

I also noticed that after adding a port to windows firewall you sometimes have to stop and start it again before it comes into effect.

To quickly test a connectionstring do the following.
Create an text file anywhere and give it extension .udl
Now doubleclick on it and the microsoft datalink property window will open, here you can enter your values and use the "test connection" button to see if it works.
Finally, if you get it working, you can open this file in notepad and there you will find a complete connectionstring.